# Java keyRelease doesn't seem to be functioning

Tags: java, key, awt, release, keyrelease

I am in the process of working through a simple tutorial for a game. When I press a button to increase the velocity the player disappears while if I add to the Y / x value it works as desired. Im assuming my problem is to do with there being something wrong with the key release part of the code. Anyways here it is if anyone could help me that'd be ideal. Thanks

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    int key = e.getKeyCode();

    for (int i=0; i<handler.object.size(); i++) {
        GameObject tempObject = handler.object.get(i);
        if (tempObject.getId() == ID.Player) {
            //Key Events for player 1
            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_W) tempObject.setY(tempObject.getY() -2);
            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_S) tempObject.setVelY(2);
            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_A) tempObject.setVelX(2);
            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_D) tempObject.setVelX(-2);
        }
        if (tempObject.getId() == ID.Player2) {
            //Key Events for player 2
            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_UP) tempObject.setVelY(-5);
            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) tempObject.setVelY(5);
            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) tempObject.setVelX(5);
            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) tempObject.setVelX(-5);
        }

    }

}
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    int key = e.getKeyCode();

    for (int i=0; i<handler.object.size(); i++) {
        GameObject tempObject = handler.object.get(i);
        if (tempObject.getId() == ID.Player) {
            //Key Events for player 1
            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_W) tempObject.setVelY(0);
            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_S) tempObject.setVelY(0);
            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_A) tempObject.setVelX(0);
            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_D) tempObject.setVelX(0);
        }
        if (tempObject.getId() == ID.Player2) {
            //Key Events for player 2
            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_UP) tempObject.setVelY(0);
            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) tempObject.setVelY(0);
            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) tempObject.setVelX(0);
            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) tempObject.setVelX(-0);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

The 'W' key press code for player 1 changes the vertical position not the velocity.

Are you perhaps only testing with the 'W' button and it's making the player move offscreen?

Comment: I know I was testing it that works but when I try change the velocity it disappears from the screen.